# GCP cloud run send a request to all running instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I have a rest API running on cloud run that implements a cache, which needs to be cleared maybe once a week when I update a certain property in the database. Is there any way to send a HTTP request to all running instances of my application? Right now my understanding is even if I send multiple requests and there are 5 instances, it could all go to one instance. So is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go back to basics:

> Cloud Run instances start based on a revision/image.

If you have the above use case, where suppose you have 5 instances running and you suddenly need to re-start them as restarting the instances resolves your use case, such as clearing/rebuilding the cache, what you need to do is:

> Trigger a change in the service/config, so a new revision gets
> created.

This will automatically replace, so will stop and **relaunch** all your instances on the fly.

You have a couple of options here, choose which is suitable for you:

1. if you have your services defined as yaml files, the easiest is to run the [replace service](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/services/replace) command:

   `gcloud beta run services replace myservice.yaml`
2. otherwise add an `Environmental` variable like a `date` that you increase, and this will yield a new revision (as a change in Env means new config, new revision) [read more](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#command-line).

   `gcloud run services update SERVICE --update-env-vars KEY1=VALUE1,KEY2=VALUE2`

As these operations are executed, you will see a new revision created, and your active instances will be replaced on their next request with fresh new instances that will build the new cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reach directly all the active instance, it's the magic (and the tradeoff) of serverless: you don't really know what is running!! If you implement cache on Cloud Run, you need a way to invalidate it.

- Either based on duration; when expired, refresh it
- Or by invalidation. ***But you can't on Cloud Run.***

The other way to see this use case is that you have a cache shared between all your instance, and thus you need a shared cache, something like [memory store](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore). You can have only 1 Cloud Run instance which invalidate it and recreate it and all the other instances will use it.